# Замена ссылок в html файлах

Tags: html, ссылки

Есть 100 картинок и 100 html файлов. В одном html файле должна быть ссылка на 1 картинку, т.е. 1.html содержит ссылку на 2.png, 2.html содержит ссылку на 2.png и так далее. Сидеть переписывать руками — не вариант, может можно как-то удобнее это сделать?

В Notepad++ и Atom такого функционала не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй написать цикл в котором будешь брать один файл картинки и создавать html файл с путем к этой картинке. И получиться у тебя небольшой конструктор который все сделает за тебя.

Answer (score 0):

В Notepad++ есть функция такая (если я вас правильно понял). Можно выделить папку, найти там текст который нужно заменить и заменить во всех. Данное меню вызывается комбинацией клавиш CTRL+F.

Comment: Нет, это, к сожалению, не совсем то, что нужно.